# Add external jar for bundle in KnopFlerFish

Tags: java, ant, import, bundle, knopflerfish

I'm trying build and run a bundle with external jar (tinyos.jar) dependy using knopflerfish.

In the compile time, there aren't problems... but in run time...

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve bundle: missing
>   package(s) or can not resolve all of the them: net.tinyos.util,
>   net.tinyos.packet, net.tinyos.message

I already put the tinyos.jar in the build path, and already play with the build.xml file a lot... in this moment the build.xml have

```
  <property name="bmfa.Bundle-Classpath" value=". , ./tinyos.jar"       />
  <property name="bmfa.Import-Package" value=" (others packages),  net.tinyos.message, net.tinyos.packet,  net.tinyos.util "/>
  <property name="bmfa.DynamicImport-Package" value="net.tinyos.message, net.tinyos.packet,  net.tinyos.util "/>
```

This didn't worked ... So .. what is the propriety that I have to set to the jar be called in run time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does tinyos.jar exist at the root of your bundle?

Comment: Yap.. I already try at a lot of locations... and didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use `Bundle-ClassPath: .,tinyos.jar` in the manifest of the bundle. The jar should be included in the root of your bundle.